# Best practices: when mobile db need clearing in social mobile iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, realm

For example, we have an iOS application that looks like facebook. In which there is a pullToRefresh and incremental loading and using realm for it.
If you do not delete data from the database, it will grow infinitely. This will affect performance.
When is it worth cleaning bd? And should it be completely cleaned? Or partially? What are the best practices?
best practices with realm?

Comment: You can delete old data using `let oldData = realm.objects(Items.self).filter(...old_data_filter...)` `realm.delete(oldData)`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to recommend any single best practice since all of this depends on your app, the size of the data it manages, and what would be a good user experience.

It's definitely a good idea to periodically clear out extremely old entries in a local cache database. But deleting a lot of data can also hurt performance, so it's not a good idea to do it too aggressively. There's nothing wrong with having a large local database, if it means it's providing a better user experience. Realm's zero-copy mechanism means it's very efficient, even when there's a lot of content.

I recommend you take a look at your app, and work out how old the data needs to be before the user will absolutely not care about it anymore. Depending on how much data your app downloads, this could be up to a day, a week or a month. Conversely, you could also set a size tolerance, so when the database grows to a size you don't like, you can then make the app start looking at shrinking it.

Since deletes can be time consuming, I'd definitely recommend you do any sort of cleaning in a background thread. You could easily set up a small class that runs an `NSOperation` periodically (Maybe once a week), queries for the oldest data in your database, and then deletes it.